# Display Alert if tableView numberOfRowsInSection == 0

Tags: ios, objective-c

I would like to display an alert if there are no results in a tableView. I using the numberOfRowsInSection like below, but the alert does not show. I also removed the if statement that checks the count in case there was something wrong with it. Does anyone know why the alert is not being displayed? Any help would be great. Thanks!

```
if ([self.listItems count] == 0)




- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
    return [self.filteredListItems count];
}

else {
    return [self.listItems count]; 
    if ([self.listItems count] == 0) {

    //CALL ALERT HERE    
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No Results" message:@"No 
    results were found" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];

    }    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't display, because you return before showing the alert:

```
else {
    return [self.listItems count]; 
...
```

Comment: Thanks! This works now, but the alert is displayed over and over again. Is there an easy fix to this or do I need to create a bool of some sort to only display once?

Comment: The better practice is not to display the alert in this method as it gets called multiple times. If you need to warn the user that there is nothing to display, you can do it, when you prepare your data source and check if there are any items in it, if not - show the alert.

Answer (score 0):

See the problem is this line `return [self.listItems count];` 
Reason is your execution is not going beyond this. Change it to :

```
else 
{
    if ([self.listItems count] == 0) 
    {
         //CALL ALERT HERE    
         UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No Results" message:@"No 
         results were found" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
         [alert show];
         return;
    }
    return [self.listItems count]; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write return statement after check if condition.

```
   if ([self.listItems count] == 0) {

    //CALL ALERT HERE    
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No Results" message:@"No 
    results were found" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];

    }  
return [self.listItems count];
```